# Why tar is incapable of changing current directory?

Tags: tar

The following command:

```
tar -C "${HOME}/temp" -zcvf uber-bundle.tgz temp
```

fail with the following error:

```
tar: temp: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

However a slightly different command works, albeit generating a tar with incorrect directory structure:

```
tar -C "${HOME}/temp" -zcvf uber-bundle.tgz ~/temp
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
...
```

It is clear that -C option fail to change the current directory of tar to ${HOME}, making directory unrecognizable. What went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

What happens here is that -C option tells tar to change directory first before creating an archive. So in the first example what you are doing is this pretty much:

```
cd /home/whatever/temp/; tar -zcvf uber-bundle.tgz temp;
```

Now are you sure you have an additional 'temp' directory in this path '/home/whatever/temp/'

In the second instance since you are using absolute path ~/temp as tar argument, even though tar changed your directory to '/home/whatever/temp/' it operates on the argument of ~/temp so you are 
doing this:

```
cd /home/whatever/temp/; tar -zcvf uber-bundle.tgz ~/temp;
```

So in this case the problem is that you are creating tar archive of directory you are currently in.